# Can NFC alone be used to transfer audio?

Tags: nfc

Can NFC be used to transfer audio like headphones cable (i.e. both ways audio and play/pause commands to an android phone) without bluetooth or other protocols?

Answer (score 0):

Nope. That won't work with the audio standards of these days.

In theory you can establish a connection of about 800 kilobits/second. In pratice that rarely happens outside the lab. In practice, with error-correction and retransmission etc, you can expect a raw data-transfer rate of 2kb/second.

That is enough to transmit recognizable speech utilizing specialized codecs for low bandwidth, but not much more. Think about audio quality from cell-phones 20 years ago and you'll get the idea.